# jQuery(...).iris is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement color picker provided here http://automattic.github.io/Iris/
Here is my libraries that i am including.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/iris.min.js"></script>
```

and this is how i am implementing this code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('#color-picker').iris(); 
});
```

this is how i have my input field

```
<input type="text" id='color-picker' value="#bada55" />
```

but i don't why i get this error

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).iris is not a function
jQuery('#color-picker').iris();
```

Comment: only include one version of jQuery library

Comment: First, you're including jquery more than once... remove all but one. Second, are you sure `js/iris.min.js` is the correct path? Check the javascript console and network tab of your browser's dev tools for errors.

Comment: @JasonP: i just checked if i can hit the `js/iris.min.js` i alerted in the file and i got `alert()`, i also removed 1 jquery , but still same result

Comment: Remove **ALL** jquery links except only **ONE** (preferably the latest).

Comment: Try using $ rather than jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like the path to your `iris` script is wrong which caused the browser cannot load the file. So you can check again to see if the path `js/iris.min.js` is correct.

You can check to see whether your file is loaded or not by going to network tab of either `Firebug` or Chrome developer tools. If it cannot load the URL which you've provided than you'll receive a `404 error not found` in this tab.

Or you can also try to replace:

```
<script src="js/iris.min.js"></script>
```

with direct link from `Github`:

```
<script src="https://github.com/Automattic/Iris/blob/master/dist/iris.min.js"></script>
```

The last note is that you just need to include jQuery once, you can choose either version `1.10.2` or `1.8.3` which you know that version will compatible with your jQuery code.

---

I think this should be something wrong with the `iris` script here, try to use this version directly from their home page:

```
<script src="http://automattic.github.io/Iris/javascripts/iris.min.js"></script>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f4dj9/)**

Comment: i tired to alert within the library that i downloaded and i got alert also i can see it in Firebug's network tab and i dont see any error for the file

Comment: `<script src="https://github.com/Automattic/Iris/blob/master/dist/iris.min.js"></script>` gave same error.

Comment: Are you using wordpress?

Comment: Do you have any live example for us to test?

Answer (score 2):

Is your code placed in a way that would let it run before jQuery, jQueryUI and Iris is loaded? Make sure you place your own script file after the rest.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/iris.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#color-picker').iris();  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have link to jQuery and jQuery UI instead of adding jQuery twice.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/iris.min.js"></script>
```

Then call iris on page load and it will work. Here is a link to working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WLru3/

PS: I have directly copy pasted code of iris in js code block, please use library link in your code instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove a line that includes jQuery 1.8.3 library
2. Make sure the path to iris.min.js is correct